# Integrate Millennial Media Icenium Webapp

Tags: javascript, cordova, icenium, millennial-media

guys.

I am trying to integrate the **millennial media** in my **webapp mobile**, but I don't have any idea about how to do this.

I using Icenium (which has cordova.js), I don't if I can do this with javascript or if I need to use server side language..

I just know that I have the **APID**.

Can anybody help me with this?
Giving me a sample and saying something like (**"put your APID here ->"**)

About 3 days trying to do this. I think this will blow up my mind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this post might help you a little: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187681/issue-with-phonegap-and-millennialmedia

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16653670/integrate-millennial-media-sdk-5-0-in-android-application